# Excel SUM of Column

Tags: excel, sum

My question is relatively simple I believe, just not getting it just yet. So here is where I am having trouble,

Let's say, Column C has numbers from C3:C33, I have other items underneath C33 but want to have a SUM of C3:C33 in Column J4 as total. That is easy enough, but when I try inserting a line at C33 to add an additional number, it doesn't automatically SUM in the cell J4. I've looked for answers and I've came across this formula:

```
    =SUM(INDIRECT("C3:C"&ROW()-1))
```

That works right under C33, and works fine if I have J4 =C33 and just simply hide that formula's row. But I'm wondering is there another Formula that will automatically auto adjust SUM from J4?

Any help would be great!

-Maykid

Comment: Is there something in the row that is unique, either below or above that you can search on to find the correct row to end?

Comment: On Row 34 there is a Totals row (the word 'Totals' is in A34) that counts how many entries are in column C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
=SUM(C3:INDEX(C:C,MATCH("Totals",A:A,0)-1))
```

Now no matter the number of rows, it will sum only those from C3 to the row above where `Totals` is found in column A.

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much! I didn't know you could use index match in a sum formula, learn something every day! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `SUM(C3:C34)` and leave C34 blank. You should now be able to insert below `C33` and the formula should automatically adjust.